# NodeJS nested Redis commands

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm quite new to this stuff, but after few attempts, I would like to ask you for a help here, because I'm not sure, what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Situation: In Redis database, I got a key `test` with values like `1,2,3,4`. To put new value into key, I use `rpush`, because I want to add new value at the end of the key (and when I run this standalone, it works as a charm):

`client.rpush("test", "5");`

However, my idea is, that first I would like to check out, if the key exists and if not, then I will add a value into it. For that I decided to use LRANGE command, now result looks like this:

```
client.lrange("test", 0, 0, function(err, reply) {
        if (reply.length === 0) {
            client.rpush("test", 5);
        }
```

Problem is, that in case described above, `rpush` seems to be 'ignored', it will not store the value. What am I doing wrong? It looks like any Redis command inside `lrange` callback is ignored.

Comment: What is the actual value of `reply`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be wanting to use `LLEN` instead of `LRANGE`.

https://redis.io/commands/llen

I am not a node guy, but something like this should work.  Your example **should** work though, if this doesn't clear it up I would go ahead and update your description to include some logging.

```
client.llen('test', function(err, reply) {  
  if (err) {
     // Log error
  }
  // Log reply 
  if (reply === 0) { 
    client.rpush('test', 5, function(err, reply) {
      if (err) {
         // Log error
      } 
      // Log reply
    })
  } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for a hint. First thing I see as difference is, that you use `rpush` as asynchronous function (correct me, if I'm wrong). Secondly - reason I use `lrange` is simple. Imagine you got ice cream truck, where people are waiting in lines for vanilla or chocolate. So you have to keys `vanilla` and `chocolate` and you are adding people into the queue. If there is nobody waiting, you will add a new name into the queue. If there is somebody waiting, you will serve the ice cream (`client.lpop('vanilla')`). I hope it makes sense.

I will return, if it's still not working, thank you!

Comment: The callback is certainly optional.  From your description, you are using lrange to determine if the `key` exists or not.  While this should work, `llen` is a more efficient way of getting that result.  In any case, if you want further help I would ask that you provide some additional logging information in your description so we can better help you with the root issue.

Comment: In the meantime, I realised that I fell into asynchronous trap. While application is working, I was calling `client.quit` on wrong place in my code. Now it works as designed, thanks!